# Eclipse folder Referenced Libraries disappears

Tags: eclipse

In Java projects in Eclipse version 3.4.1 sometimes the folder "Referenced Libraries" disappears from the "Project Explorer" view. All third party jars are shown directly in the root of the project folder. The project compiles and runs fine. It seems to be a GUI problem.

How can I get this folder back?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

First, bring up the "Package Explorer" view (instead of the "Project Explorer" view).

Then, if the referenced .jar files still are visible in the root of the project, click on the little "down arrow" icon in the top-right corner of the Package Explorer view. In the context menu that appears, one of the items on the menu is "Show 'Referenced Libraries' Node."  Click on that menu item.

Comment: Thx, this helped solving the problem! But it's not quite the answer. Could you please add "Use the Package Explorer view instead of the Project Explorer view". Than I can accept this as the good answer.

Comment: @Bno, glad I could help!  I had just run into this issue a month or two ago, so the solution was still fresh in my mind.  I edited the answer as you suggested.

Comment: Amazing... i use Eclipse for 5 years now, and i never liked the (sometimes) huge list of libraries inside project root. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I've been struggling with this thing for a while in **Eclipse Juno** because it's a little bit different.

- click the little `down arrow` as before
- click `Customize view`
- check `Libraries from external`

Answer (score 2):

For those hitting the issue today (Kepler): it is possible that you are in the "Java EE" perspective, which by default has the Project Explorer. Simply switch to the "Java" perspective and it will replace Project Explorer with Package Explorer, which will have the missing Referenced Libraries folder.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're actually in Project Explorer and not in some other view like Navigator, like my friend was...

Answer (score 0):

Use the Package Explorer view instead of the Project Explorer view.